# Where to check for Firebase Realtime Database Location (US, EU, or Asia)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-console

I'm a developer in Australia and and I'm using the Firebase Realtime database for a project on Android and iOS.

Customers are complaining about lag and delays, especially when logging-in, and I'm trying to find out if any Firebase processes are by default on US servers, but can be moved to Asia to improve performance.

When I check my Google Cloud Console, the default Storage Bucket is set up as the US, but I cannot find any information about the Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Lag and delay can be caused by many factors. I am using firebase REST Api (slower than Javascript), but have never faced any delays is response.

Comment: See [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore#reliability_and_performance) - Firebase realtime DB is single-region (US) and Cloud Firestore is multi (albeit currently in Beta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the RTDB console you can see it at the bottom as indicated in the image. This feature is currently in a beta state. https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations?authuser=0#rtdb-locations

[image]

Comment: Regions available for selection can be seen at https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations

Answer (score 18):

**Update**: as of late 2020 Firebase Realtime Database instances can be in different locations. You can find the location of your database as the bottom of the data viewer in the Firebase console, as also shown in the screenshot in Jürgen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66311870/209103).

<strike>All  Firebase Databases are hosted in the central US. There is no way to change this at the moment.</strike>

Comment: Are there any plans to allow customers to choose where their Firebase Database is hosted?

Comment: Is this was change lately?

Comment: We are getting very slow loading times of page in india approx 6-7 second while after adding cdn through cloud function i see a huge performance gain of around 100ms , because the servers are located at us therefore ttfb (waiting) is high in other countries , i want to know is there a way i can speed up fiebase read from database first time so that page loading becomes fast?. This is the only problem i fear of using it in production .

Comment: Hi Frank, how are you? I want to ask if Firebase has any plans to support multiple locations for the realtime database as well (similar to firestore)?
I ask this because of recent changes by the EU that invalidates the US-EU privacy shield (Schrems II case).
Thanks